# Nissan Altima 2011 TPMS light on

Tags: tires, nissan, altima, tire-pressure, tire-pressure-monitoring-system

I have one Altima 2011 S Sedan with 48000 miles. Yesterday, I went to one Mavis tire shop to replace 4 new tires. After I drove back home, I found that the **valve cap of the left front tire** (driver's side) is missing. Then I drove back to that Mavis and let them installed the missing valve cap, after that, I drove to one Outlets and it was about 60 miles for the whole round trip and everything was good.

Today, When I was driving over a hump, I didn't control the steering wheel well so that **the right front tire went first then followed by the left front tire**, and at that moment, the TPMS light was on.

I was thinking the tire pressure was low so I drove to a gas station and tried to use the air pump to inflate my tires. Then I found that my **left front tire pressure was 38psi and right front tire was 36 psi**, but based on the tag stuck under the door, the **cold psi is only 32 psi for each tire**.

So I used air pump to release the pressure to 32 psi for each tire and the tpms light didn't off until I drove for about 1 minute with a low speed about 20 mph. after that, I drove for 20 miles and turn-off restart my car for several times and the tpms light never on again, but I'm still not sure what is the reason the tpms was on and anything necessary I need to do?

Comment: First, you should control your tyre pressures when cold, not after driving and warming the tyres. Once you have set the pressures then, if they are working correctly, all should be fine.

Comment: Follow up (one day later after asking): it was snowing this morning(33 F degree) while yesterday was a sunny day ( over 60 F degree). The tpms light on again and I found the four tire pressures were around 29 psi, then I did the same thing for all my tires and the light gone very quickly. Then I googled that every 10 F goes down, 1 psi goes down which makes sense. Since this time is snowing when I pumping tires, and hopefully after this time, everything goes well.